# kohana data access layer where to put custom database queries

Tags: php, kohana-3

I am using kohana 3 with jelly as my orm

I have created my models, which map to the database tables

Now i also have some custom database queries that are called from more then 1 place

I was thinking of coding them up as static methods in my model class, is that the best place to put them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are both pros and cons for this solution. Personally I often use static method when it needs to be called in the view, for everything else I create objects and play with ORM.
I find [this thread](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/9598/static-methods-vs-a-table-class-architecturetestability-question) on Kohana forums very usefull.